# Planning a document generation project; Looking for output format suggestions

Tags: file-io

I am currently working on a project at work where we have a fairly large document that we manually fill out results for, which seems to me to be archaic and needlessly time consuming.

I've decided to take it upon myself to draft up a proposal to streamline this process and present it to my higher-ups once I have it fleshed out a bit more. I am looking for suggestions of an output format for the document I am writing.

The document is mostly tables with pass/fail fields. I am looking to automatically check the results and fill in the gaps properly (assume that I have the methods to do this). I need a way to output a file that can be edited after generation, because due to the nature of the failures we will still need to manually assess the fails.

My first thought was Latex, but I do not believe that there is an easily editable output format. My next thought was word, but I've read that generating word documents through automation is a painful process.

Any suggestions would be great,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the output file to look reasonable, I would consider plain HTML, which is quite editable in a simple text editor as long as it's generated cleanly (i.e. with line breaks and indentation just as it would be written by a human). You can apply a static stylesheet to it to prettify it if that's important to you, but the stylesheet would be static and wouldn't require editing. Simple HTML should look readable in a standard browser without a stylesheet, but will be rather plain.

Editing the results might require a small amount of training among non-technical users, but not too much - you might find you can edit the pages successfully in Word, but I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't mangle them when you save them back out. The mangling probably wouldn't be an issue for human readability, but might complicate a tool which tries to later automatically parse it. This is something that you'd have to experiment with.

The other option would be to write out simple CSV files that can be easily edited with a text editor or spreadsheet application - these might be easier for non-technical Windows users as they could use Excel or an open source equivalent. The presentation of these is a bit messy, however, unless you load them into a spreadsheet application - you could have a separate "publication" stage which automatically converted them to a prettier read-only form, however.

If you have other constraints which make these suggestions inappropriate, please detail them so we can provide more assistance.